# How do I rewrite URLs using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the following URL:

```
http://www.myurl.com/job/Accounting-Clerk-at-Department-of-Workforce-Services-in-Salt-Lake-City,-UT-1b6117567108f5a2
```

Into these components:

```
query = Accounting Clerk;
cmp = Department of Workforce Services;
location = Salt Lake City, UT;
key = 1b6117567108f5a2;
```

To get this result:

```
index.php?q=$query&cmp=$cmp&l=$location&key=$key
```

Comment: I don't think you need so much junk in your URL

Comment: "Teach me" aren't the kind of questions we want here.

Comment: Are you working for Indeed? http://www.indeed.com/job/Accounting-Clerk-at-Department-of-Workforce-Services-in-Salt-Lake-City,-UT-1b6117567108f5a2

Comment: @Marius - errr... surely "Teach me" are exactly the sort of questions we want here. Don't most of us have the "Teacher" badge (http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1/teacher), which I notice is listed as badge 1.

Answer (score 4):

Try this [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^job/([^/]+)-at-([^/]+)-in-([^/]+)-([0-9a-f]+)$ index.php?q=$1&cmp=$2&l=$3&key=$4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule job/([^.]+)-in-([^.]+) index.php?var1=$1&var2ext=$2
```

etc continue like that